# get Checkbox binding value

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I have a popup window that a user can open and close as many times as they like. On the window there is 4 checkboxes with checked values that are bound. The idea is that if a user un-checks a box then closes the window it will still be unchecked the next time it is opened. When the window opens if there are any check boxes that are un-checked I need to do some work. My problem is that when in the codebehind in the WindowLoadedEvent I try to get the check boxes value to see if I need to do some work first. Every time the window loads all the isChecked values for every checkbox are false even though when the window shows they are all checked.

I don't know how to get the value I am looking for I am using .net 4.0;

```
      <StackPanel x:Name="panelVisibilities">
                                <CheckBox x:Name="crossCorrelationViewCheck"                                 
                                          IsChecked="{Binding Path=Processor.CrossCorrelation.IsCrossCorrelationVisible}"
                                          Click="GraphVisibilityClickEvent"
                                          HorizontalAlignment="Left"/>
    ...etc


private void WindowLoadedEvent(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
    IEnumerable<CheckBox> elements = this.panelVisibilities.Children.OfType<CheckBox>().ToList();            

                foreach (CheckBox uiElement in elements)
                {

                    bool isChecked = uiElement.DataContext;

                    if (isChecked == false)
                    {
                        //do work
                    }
                }
    }
```

Edit:
A better way to explain it might be I have a checkbox.IsChecked bound to a model, but I want to check its state from the xaml code behind when the window is displayed.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: what? Do not manipulate UI elements in code in WPF. If the checkboxes are bound... what are they bound to? why don't you manipulate those data items instead?

Comment: Can't you just check id `Processor.CrossCorrelation.IsCrossCorrelationVisible` is true or false? why are you checking the element?

Comment: I can not check Processor.CrossCorrelation.IsCrossCorrelationVisible because I cannot see it from the xaml code behind. It is a model property that is to the checbox, and not visible from the code behind.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think there may be two problems in your code.

First: Does `bool isChecked = uiElement.DataContext;` really work?
  `uiElement` is a CheckBox, and `uiElement.DataContext` is `null`. 
You can use `uiElement.IsChecked.Value` to get the value.

Second:  You must set the properties of `Processor.CrossCorrelation.IsCrossCorrelationVisible` before the `WindowLoadedEvent` occurred. You can check your inner code.

Comment: Processor.CrossCorrelation.IsCrossCorrelationVisible is set before the window is opened. That is on the model that is bound to the checkbox. I am trying to check the value of IsCrossCorrelationVisible from the xaml code behind.

Comment: The code on your xaml IsChecked="{Binding Path=Processor.CrossCorrelation.IsCrossCorrelationVisible}"
would you try this :  IsChecked="{Binding Processor.CrossCorrelation.IsCrossCorrelationVisible}" and please make sure CheckBox's DataContext is the Processor